# Getting Unix path of multiple files/folders in Automator service

Tags: unix, terminal, shell, applescript, automator

I want to get path of (multiple) file(s, folders) in Automator service by selecting them in Finder and then use them in shell command.

I already have something like this:

**Launch AppleScript:**

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "clamscan --bell -i " & POSIX path of input
end tell
```

end run

This works, but only for one file or folder and it does not convert `/path/file with spaces` to `/path/file\ with\ spaces`.

So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing this in **Automator**, with a **Run AppleScript** *acton*, this will do what you need:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set theItemsToScanList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count input
        set end of theItemsToScanList to quoted form of (POSIX path of (item i of input as string)) & space
    end repeat

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "clamscan --bell -i " & theItemsToScanList
    end tell

end run
```

There is no need to complicate things and go through the rigmarole shown in the other answer!

---

Or if you choose to do it in a plain **AppleScript** *script/application*,  then this will do what you need:

```
set theseItems to application "Finder"'s selection

set theItemsToScanList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count theseItems
    set end of theItemsToScanList to quoted form of (POSIX path of (item i of theseItems as string)) & space
end repeat

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "clamscan --bell -i " & theItemsToScanList
end tell
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is just that, and does not include any *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* for any *example code* presented and or *code* written by the oneself.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
property posixPathofSelectedFinderItems : {}
property QposixPathofSelectedFinderItems : {}
-- stores the selected files in the active finder window
-- in the variable "these_items"
tell application "Finder"
    set these_items to the selection
end tell

-- returns the Posix Path of each of those files and 
-- stores all of that info in the "posixPathofSelectedFinderItems"
-- as a list
repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
    set this_item to (item i of these_items) as alias
    set this_info to POSIX path of this_item
    set end of posixPathofSelectedFinderItems to this_info
end repeat

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in posixPathofSelectedFinderItems
    set this_item to item i of posixPathofSelectedFinderItems
    set this_item to quoted form of this_item
    set end of QposixPathofSelectedFinderItems to (this_item & " ")
end repeat
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "clamscan --bell -i " & items of QposixPathofSelectedFinderItems
end tell
set posixPathofSelectedFinderItems to {}
set QposixPathofSelectedFinderItems to {}
```

Comment: The OP is using Terminal's `do script` _command_ not AppleScript's `do shell script` _command_. The immediate issue I see you your answer is if more then one file and say lots of files are selected, while the `--bell` _option_ of the `clamscan` _command_ may ring, so to speak, how is one going to know which of the lots of files selected is the infected one? `-i`, which would print infected files, is useless in a `do shell script` _command_ unless you're going to set its _output_ to a _variable_ and then parse it some how,  but not in Terminal's `do script` _command_. Something to think about!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up..  Working on another post at the moment but I will come back to this one shortlyAnd make the necessary changes

Comment: The final output to shell command must be this: clamscan -I —bell ‘/path/file1’ ‘/path/file 2’ e.t.c.

Comment: Addressed the issue..  Updated the code

Comment: Your answer has unneeded properties, which you are setting **and** unsetting, unneeded multiple `repeat` _loops_. The OP is using **Automator** and a **Run AppleScript** _action_, so the only _variable_, and it doesn't need to be a `property`, is `theItemsToScanList` as a `list`, and only one `repeat` _loop_ to process the `items of input` into it, with a single _command_ line within the `repeat` _loop_. You're using 21 lines of _code_ where it can be done with 8 lines of _code_ added to the **Run AppleScript** _acton_ in order to achieve the goal of the OP.